# Render cryptomatte pass with python

Tags: python, rendering, cryptomatte

I have a scene in scene in Blender:

[image]

Through python I generate copies of a metal part you can see on the left, drop them into the box and then render. Then, based on a condition, some metal parts are marked as 'visible'.

I need to render the scene as is, and then render a mask only for 'visible' parts. After I'm done with rendering the scene and the mask I delete the parts and generate a new batch, repeating the process

So far, to get the mask, I've been changing material of visible objects to emission, but I was told in my previous question here that there's a built in method for this - cryptomatte. However, I couldn't figure out how to actualy implement it.

The question is: **What functions specifically do I need to call to save cryptomatte image of 'visible' objects?**

Here's the function that executes the render

```
def render_scene(objects, visible_objects, box_obj, i):
    curr_path = FOLDER_PATH + '/IMG' + f'{i:03}' + "/IMG" + f'{i:03}_'
    
    # RAW RENDER
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = curr_path + 'render.png'
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
    
    
    # set up render for mask
    # hide everything that shouldn't be in the mask
    set_transparent([box_obj])
    set_transparent(objects)
    set_opaque(visible_objects)
    light = bpy.data.objects['Light']
    light.hide_render = True
    
    # MASK RENDER

    # somehow access cryptomate and save it as an image

    # Return to settings for raw
    set_opaque([box_obj])
    set_opaque(objects)
    light.hide_render = False
    
    return i + 1
```

`set_transparent` and `set_opaque` simply toggle hide_render property for objects

Comment: are you perhaps talking about the Holdout mask -- where  ```for o in objects:  o.is_holdout = True```?